# SPOJ Prime generator Wrong Answer

Tags: primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Here is the link to the problem-:http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/.
The problem asks to find all prime numbers between a given rang
`1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000`, `n-m<=100000`.
I have implemented Segmented Sieve 
Here is the logic-:
As the problem has maximum value of 10^9, so I will find all primes withing square_root(10^9) which is around 31622.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void Prime1(long int low, long int high, bool* pre)
{
    bool prime[high-low+1]={0};

    if(low==high)
        {if(pre[low]==0)printf("%ld\n", low);return;}
    int t=sqrt(high);
    for(long int i=2;i<=t;i++)
    {
        if(pre[i]==1)continue;
        long int a=ceil(((double)low/i))*i;// start value
        long int b=floor(((double)high/i))*i;// end value
        if(a==1)
            continue;
        if(a==i)
            a+=i;
        if(a==0)
            a=2*i;
        for(long int x=a;x<=high;x+=i)
        {
            prime[x-low]=1;
        }
    }
    if(low==1)
        prime[0]=1;
    else if(low==0)
        prime[0]=prime[1]=1;
    for(int i=0;i<=(high-low);i++)
        if(!prime[i])printf("%ld\n", i+low);
}
int main()
{

    bool pre[32001];
    pre[0]=pre[1]=1;

    int x=sqrt(32001);
    for(int i=2;i<=x;i++)
    {
        if(pre[i]==0)
        {
            for(int j=i;i*j<=32000;j++)
            {
                pre[i*j]=1;
            }
        }
    }

    int t;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    long low, high;
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%ld %ld",&low, &high);
        printf("\n")
        Prime1(low, high, pre);

    }
}
```

Now I'll start from i=2 and find its multiples between m and n. Here m and n represent low and high respectively.
I'll keep on increasing i till `i<=sqrt(n)`
For example, m=125 and n=140
a=((double)m/i)*i. I'll consider its ceiling value.
So, when `m=125` `i=2`
`a=126`.
so, `126+(2*k)` are all composite where k>=0.
The same is for `i=3,5,7.....`

When I submit it on SPOJ, it gives me WA. 
I have used spoj toolkit which contained some test cases. I compared it with the other code and getting same result.
What am I missing?

Comment: You print a blank line with `printf("\n")` before outputting the answer, this could be a problem.

Comment: @DAle I already tried it. Still WA

Comment: and you have an error here: `if(low==high) {if(pre[low]==0)printf("%ld\n", low);return;}`.

Comment: @DAle Its still not working. And why is the if statement error?

Comment: the problem is in `pre[low]`, `low` can be `10^9`, and `pre` is not that large.